# Android background that ripples when pressed, but solid color when selected?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a drawable that ripples when it's pressed, but when `view.setSelected(true)` is called, it holds a solid color for a background.

**The following file is placed in my drawable-v21 folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <color android:color="@color/green_primary" />
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <ripple android:color="@color/green_primary">
            <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/green_selected" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I've tried the above, and it holds a solid background when it's selected, but there isn't a ripple effect, rather just kind of a fade-in effect. If I just have the ripple with no selector, it ripples correctly when pressed, but obviously then I don't have a `selected` state. How could I have both baked into a single background drawable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Create a **ripple_effect.xml** file in `drawable-v21` folder

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/green_primary">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_primary"/>
</ripple>
```

2. Create **button_selector.xml** file in `drawable` folder to set the selected state color.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
            android:drawable="@color/green_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi @MihirShah : I think you should create a custom shaped drawable having a rounded corner, and set it in here `<item android:drawable="@drawable/green_primary"/>`